# Can I travel with a refugee document issued by Canada, to USA, UK, and India?

Tags: visas, international-travel, paperwork, refugees

I have a refugee travel document that is issued by Canada and I need to travel to USA, UK, and India. Can I do travel to those countries with a refugee travel document issued by Canada? And do I need to apply or is visa-free entry permitted?

Which countries allow visa free travel to any person holding a refugee travel document issued by Canada?

Comment: the second part of your question is way too broad

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule - [and it is the same for Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=610&top=11) - refugee travel document is valid for travel to all countries except the one you claimed the persecution from. I.e. if you fled USA and granted refugee status in Canada, you cannot use this document to travel to USA.

Regarding the question "whether I can entry country X only with a refugee travel document or I also need a visa", you shall [use Timatic](https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/). Make sure you enter your document as "refugee travel document" and not "passport".